# Finding Final Arrangement

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I came across this question in recent interview :

Given an array of pairs representing a number inserted at which position, we need to find final arrangement. If there is already a number at that position, we need to shift array from that position to the right and put that number at desired position.

e.g. A = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}, B = {0, 1, 2, 1, 2} (Ai represents a number and Bi represents its desired position ) , so, array C can be filled as follows :

C = {0, _, _, _, _} => {0,1, _ ,_ ,_ } => {0,1,2,_ ,_ } =>{0,3,1,2,_ } =>{0,3,4,1,2}

Constaints : 0 <= Ai, Bi < N (N is length of an array)

We need to find final array C. I need better approach than applying brute force for this solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: Think about inserting the numbers in reverse order. The *last* insertion always goes in its desired place; what effect does it have on the final locations of earlier insertions? That "effect" can be calculated straightforwardly in O(n) time per insertion, or less straightforwardly in O(log n) time per insertion using certain data structures.

Comment: Yes, that's what I am asking. What is approach to do it in O(log n). I have heard that fenwick tree works here but didn't understood how to use it.

Comment: Yes, a Fenwick tree would work well for this. But instead of just telling you the answer, I'm trying to get you to discover it for yourself. I suggest describing in words what you need to compute for each insertion in reverse order, and coming up with a straightforward way to compute that in O(n) time per insertion. Then read about Fenwick trees and see if you can apply them to speed this up to O(log n).

Answer (score 0):

First, let's consider the `T` operator which for a position `i`, returns `T(i) = i+1` (that is the element is switched to the right)
Obviously, `T(T(i)) = i+2`, and we can note `T^n(i) = i+n`

Now consider a linked list whose node is

```
{
    idx: i,//idx of the value upon insertion (as found in B)
    value:value,
    tn:Number //T^n
}
```

pseudo code be like

```
insertElem(L, i, val):
    node = L
    while node
        acc += node.tn //sum all the shifts
        curIdx = node.idx + acc
        if curIdx == i:
            insertElemBefore(node, i, val)
            node.tn++
            return
        if curIdx > i:
            insertElemBefore(node, i, val)
        node = node.next
    //we could not find any elem to shift
    //just insert elem at the end
```

```js
function insertElem(L, i, val){
    let el = {idx:i, val:val, tn:0}
    let acc = 0;
    let front = L;
    while(L.next){
        let next = L.next;
        acc += next.tn;
        if(acc + next.idx >= i){
            L.next = el;
            if(acc + next.idx == i){
                el.next = next;
                next.tn++;
            }
            return front;
        }
        L = L.next;
    }
    L.next = el;
    el.next = null;
    return front;
}
function main(A,B){
    let L = {next:null}
    B.forEach((idx,i)=>{
        L = insertElem(L, idx, A[i]);
    });
    let v = [];
    while(L = L.next){
        v.push(L.val);
    }
    return v;
}
console.log(main([0,1,2,3,4],[0,1,2,1,2]))
```